# HP SmartArray P212 with non HP disks, Insight Diagnostics error

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an ML110 G6 with a SmartArray P212 and two Seagate (non-HP) SAS disks in Raid 1.

When I ran HP Insight Diagnostics I got some errors related to S.M.A.R.T. error testing and I would like to confirm that this is due to the controller not being able to query the drives as they are non-HP.

I believe that the drives are not failing, but I want to be sure.

Please have a look at these screenshots I took from the Insight Diagnostics report:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're *probably* just fine but you won't ever really know because HP controllers are configured to work with HP-specific firmware, by not using HP disks you lose out on this function.

Comment: Right I understand, but as they passed all the other Insight Diagnostic tests I assume that if they _weren't_ fine I would have gotten more errors. No?

Comment: @yonatan no, HP controllers are configured to work with HP-specific firmware, as in *only HP-specific firmware*. The fact that they may or may not work with other drives is completely incidental, and not intentional.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe due to the NON-HP Firmware of the hard drives. HP Hard Drives are usually outsourced, flashed with HP FW and rebranded. I am not really sure which features will not be active, but for regular usage, the drives should be okay.

Comment: HP has no ability to produce their own drives, they all come from the only 3 hard drive manufactures (Western Digital, Seagate, or Toshiba). All of their "server" drives currently come from Seagate.